# React-Native TextInput for registering a user Why is the typed text is not displaying or being stored into the setInput object?

Tags: react-native

Hello I am trying to navigate creating a text input on React-Native that lets the user enter their email password and name and stores it in the object. But it is not working how I expected and I am not sure where I have gone wrong. I have looked at similar projects online but most are done with React not react-natie and even still when i try their implementation it still doesnt fix the text not displaying as i type or allowing it to be store when the user presses the register button.

````
import { Text, View, TextInput, Button, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {useState} from 'react';


export default function Home() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState({
    fullName:"",
    email:"",
    password: "",
  });
  const inputHandler = (e) => {
    let name = e.target.fullName
    let value = e.target.value;
    setInput({
      ...input,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };
  const registerUser = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(input)
    setInput({
      fullName:"",
      email: "",
      password:"",
    });
  };
  return (
    <View >
      <Text style={styles.welcome}>
        Welcome! Please Register Below
      </Text>
      <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="Name"  value={input.fullName} onChangeText={inputHandler}/>
      <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="Email"  value={input.email} onChangeText={inputHandler}/>
      <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="Password" value={input.password} onChangeText={inputHandler} />
      <View style={styles.button}>
      <Button title="Register" onPress={registerUser} />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.button}>
      <Button title="Already Registered? Click here to login" onPress={()=> register()} />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  welcome:{
    padding:10
  },
  input: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
    borderColor:'black',
    borderWidth: 2,
    margin:3
  },
  button:{
    margin:5
  }
});```

I have tried this.input.fullName in the value prop but that give me an error as that is not the way i defined it with my handlers. I also could go back to just using seperate states for each input like [name,setName] [password,setPassword] ect... but I would really like to understand where my knowledge is lacking for utilizing TextInput to pass user information and storing it.

From looking through similar stackoverflow questions I also tried changing my onChangeText to this

`onChangeText={(t) =>inputHandler(t)}`

but that also doesnt solve it

Thanks!
````

Answer (score 0):

Text is not displayed, because you react on changes, but not change state properly. `onTextChanges` callback return to you only `text` (as string), not as `Event`. If you need track `Event` you can use `onChange` callback.

But, I recommend to you write your logic as clean and simple as possible.
Firstly, you should separate `inputHandler` to independent text changes functions, because it easily to manage for now in your case. For example:

```
  const onNameChanges = (text) => {
    setInput(prev => ({
      ...prev,
      fullName: text
    }))
  }
```

And then just assign it to props of your `TextInput`

```
 <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="Name"  value={input.fullName} onChangeText={onNameChanges}/>
```

That's it. You code works as expected. I prepared working example for you here
https://snack.expo.dev/BkQi-kXr-8